# map with red dots

Tags: jquery

I have a world map, containing red dots, 
when you hover over the dots,
a list of countries shows up ( it could be 1 or many)
all the items on the list are links going to a section on an inventory page.

I'm just learning jquery, so i'm facing a few issues, perhaps some one can help me with:

1. I need the list of countries to auto resize according to height or     rows of countries there are
2. there should be only one list displaying at a time.
3. once i mouseover on a dot and it displays countries, and mouse out
   it does not work again until i refresh the page
4. does my jquery code make sense, is there a better way?

This is what most of the divs look like on the html section:

```
 <div id="austDiv32">
 <img class="dot5" src="../images/dot.png" alt="Austria" style="margin: 80px 0 0 450px;" />
 <div id="Div32" class="theDiv" style="margin: 20px 0 0 460px;">
 <a href="availability.aspx?region=Austria" class="style1">Austria/a> 
 <a href="availability.aspx?region=Czech_Republic-Hungary"class="style1">
 CzechRepublic<br />Hungary</a> 
 <a href="availability.aspx?region=Serbia" class="style1">Serbia</a>
 </div>
 </div>
```

This is what the jquery looks like:

```
    $(function () {

        $(".dot").mouseover(function () {
            $(this).parent().children("div").animate({ height: "130px" }, 1000).css("visibility", "visible").delay(3000);
        });

        $(".dot").mouseout(function () {
            $(this).parent().children("div").fadeOut(600).removeClass(".theDiv");
        })


        $(".dot2").mouseover(function () {
            $(this).parent().children("div").animate({ height: "18px" }, 1000).css("visibility", "visible").delay(1000);

        });

        $(".dot2").mouseout(function () {
            $(this).parent().children("div").fadeOut(600).removeClass(".theDiv");

        });


        $(".dot3").mouseover(function () {
            $(this).parent().children("div").animate({ height: "30px" }, 1000).css("visibility", "visible").delay(1000);
        })

        $(".dot3").mouseout(function () {
            $(this).parent().children("div").fadeOut(600).removeClass(".theDiv").end();

        });

        $(".dot4").mouseover(function () {
            $(this).parent().children("div").animate({ height: "50px" }, 1000).css("visibility", "visible").delay(1000);
        })

        $(".dot4").mouseout(function () {
            $(this).parent().children("div").fadeOut(600).removeClass(".theDiv");

        });


        $(".dot5").mouseover(function () {
            $(this).parent().children("div").animate({ height: "70px" }, 1000).css("visibility", "visible").delay(1000);
        })

        $(".dot5").mouseout(function () {
            $(this).parent().children("div").fadeOut(600).removeClass(".theDiv");

        });

        $(".dot6").mouseover(function () {
            $(this).parent().children("div").animate({ height: "145px" }, 1000).css("visibility", "visible").delay(1000);
        })

        $(".dot6").mouseout(function () {
            $(this).parent().children("div").fadeOut(600).removeClass(".theDiv");

        });



    }); 

</script>
```

Comment: You really need to put together a little demo so people can see what's going wrong. Try posting on jsfiddle.net, then post the URL back here.

Comment: This is what most of the divs look like:

 <div id="austDiv32">
        <img class="dot5" src="../images/dot.png" alt="Austria" style="margin: 80px 0 0 450px;" />
        <div id="Div32" class="theDiv" style="margin: 20px 0 0 460px;">
            <a href="availability.aspx?region=Austria" class="style1">Austria</a> 
            <a href="availability.aspx?region=Czech_Republic-Hungary"
                class="style1">Czech Republic<br />
                Hungary</a> 
            <a href="availability.aspx?region=Serbia" class="style1">Serbia</a>
        </div>
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to the problem, but it will help you make better code:

Instead of repeating the same code over and over again with different values, have your elements contain the data you need. Then you only need one function for the whole set.

For example:

```
<div class='dot' data-aniHeight='18px'></div>
```

JS:

```
$(".dot").mouseover(function () {
    var aniHeight = $(this).data('aniHeight');
    $(this).parent().children("div").animate({ height: aniHeight }, 1000).css("visibility", "visible").delay(1000);
});
```